# Using Observables in Express Routing Middleware causes headers to be set after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, timeout, rxjs, observable

I am using Observable (Rxhttp specifically). I am also using connect-timeout to timeout long running requests. Unfortunately, my `.subscribe` appears to still run, even when the error handling middleware has been hit, and should have ostensibly closed the connection.

This often results in a:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

A minimal reproducible case is below.

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const timeout = require('connect-timeout')
const Rx = require('rx')
const http = require('http')

let app = express()
app.use(timeout('1s'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //in the real application the Rx is an external request
  return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.onNext({
      response: 'potato'
    })
    observer.onCompleted()
  })
  .delay(new Date(Date.now() + 1500))
  .subscribe((x) => {
    console.log('this runs')
    res.status(200).send()
  }, (e) => {
    console.log('this does not')
  })
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if(err) {
    res.status(500).send('SOMETHING BROKE!')
  }
})

const httpServer = http.createServer(app)
httpServer.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port %d.', 3000)
})
```

How could I avoid this issue? Why is the `.subscribe` still running even though the middleware has been timed out?
I know I can avoid this by chaining a `.timeout` on the observable, but this has the flaw that it does not necessarily correspond to the connect timeout (e.g, a database read could have happened, the request in aggregate could have taken more than a second, while the observable itself does not).
Is there a more generic solution?

Answer (score 0):

`Connection-timeout` npm works like this.

`delay()` function delays the the responses as many milliseconds as you give it to. In this case the responses are delayed 1.5 seconds. So the client will not get the response until 1.5 seconds pass.

`app.use(timeout('1s'))` function checks if the response was sent after 1 second the request was received, in this case, the responses are not send until 1.5 seconds have past, so it returns an error even though response is being sent later on.

My code, my server checks 5 seconds later if the response was sent, if it was not it returns an error.

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const timeout = require('connect-timeout')
const Rx = require('rx')
const http = require('http')

let app = express()
app.use(timeout('5s'));   // if can't send the response in 5 seconds, it will return request timeout error

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //in the real application the Rx is an external request
  Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.onNext({
      response: 'potato'
    })
    observer.onCompleted()
  })
  .delay(new Date(Date.now() + 1000)) // I am delaying the requests 1 seconds
  .subscribe((x) => {
    console.log(x);
    console.log('this runs')
    res.status(200).send()
  }, (e) => {
    console.log('this does not')
  })
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send('SOMETHING BROKE!')
  }
})

const httpServer = http.createServer(app)
httpServer.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port %d.', 3000)
})
```

So my responses from the server will be sent one second after the request was received and the server will check to see if it was sent 5 seconds later, if it wasn't it will return `Service Unavailable: Request Timeout.`

Comment: I'm sorry I may have been unclear, my delay is deliberately simulating the timing out case, but the subscribe still runs...

Comment: That is because subscribe is meant to run after the delay, it's error handler is not. @AbrahamP